# Solving the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = (2x-3)(3y+4)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that the solution to the differential equation, using algebraic methods
$\frac{dy}{dx} = (2x-3)(3y+4)$ is $y=A[e^{(3x^2-9x)}-B]$ where $A = \frac{e^{3c}}{3}$ and $B = \frac{4}{3A}$

Comment: I don't like the provided solution.. $c$ is an arbitrary constant and $\frac {e^{3c}}{3}$ is just as arbitrary.  I would much prefer to see $y = Ce^{3x^2 - 9x} - \frac 43$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have: $\dfrac{dy}{3y+4} = (2x-3)dx \implies \displaystyle \int \dfrac{dy}{3y+4} = \displaystyle \int (2x-3)dx\implies \dfrac{\ln(3y+4)}{3} = x^2-3x+c\implies \ln(3y+4) = 3x^2 - 9x + 3c \implies 3y+4 = e^{3x^2-9x+3c}\implies y = \dfrac{e^{3x^2-9x+3c} - 4}{3}= A[e^{3x^2-9x} - B]$ as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite the equation as:
$$y' - 3(2x-3)y = 4(2x-3) $$
Which is just a first order linear ODE. 
Let $\mu = e^{-\int (6x - 9)dx} $ and multiply the equation by $\mu $

Note that:
$$\frac{d}{dx} (\mu y) = 4 \mu (2x-3) $$
So the solution will be:
$$y = \mu^{-1} \int 4 \mu (2x-3)dx$$